# separate file into several

Tags: file, awk, cut

I have a textfile that has several paragraphs, which I want to cut into separate files. It should work of a Linux system.

for example:
first I have this File:

```
== 01.01.2014 ==
this is the text that should 
go into

file one
and i like file one to be namend 01-01-2014

== 15.02.2014 ==
and this is the text that should
end up 
in file two

where file two is named 
15-02-2014
```

and the cutting it should have two files, named 15-02-2014.txt and 01-01-2014.txt containing only the textpart belonging to the date, one problem may be that there are linebreaks and empty lines in between, so a file could contain several text blocks

I thought there would be a solution using awk, but I don't know how to save it to different files. 
My other approach was using libreoffice writer, but it seems that its search and replace function does not allow inserting a pagebreak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
awk '/^==/ {out=$2} {print > out".txt"}' file
```

It will use the date after  `==` as the name of the output file.

Comment: Many Thanks! Thats works perfect. I am sorry, I dont have enough reputation to upvote it. Will accept it as soon I am allowed to